Can not query users with at least one item of a given array in typeorm (querybuilder)
I have a user table on a Postgres db. A user can have multiple achievements where achievement are its own type T_ACHIEVEMENT_USER
Now I want to write a simple query with typeorm where I get all users which have at least one of a given achievements includeAchievement but do not have one of given excludedAchievements.
However I can not even get a version with only the includedAchievements working.
 const queryBuilder = this.providedRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .where(`user.achievements IN (:...achievements)`, { achievements: includedAchievements });
// includedAchievement is of type: ('GOLDEN' | 'SILVER' | 'PLATIN' | 'DIAMOND')[]


Which give me this error:
malformed array literal: \"GOLDEN\""

I tried to cast the includedAchievements like this:
    const castedAchievements = includedAchievements.map(a => `"${a}"::public.T_ACHIEVEMENTS_USER`);


But this also resulted in a 'malformed' error.
Then I tried to build a condition using ArrayContains like this
 const condition: { [key: string]: unknown } = {
      ...(includeAchievements.concat(excludedAchievements).length > 0 && {
        achievements: And(
          ...[
            ...(includedAchievements.length > 0 ? [ArrayContains(includedAchievements)] : []),
            ...(excludedAchievements.length > 0 ? [Not(ArrayContains(excludedAchievements))] : []),
          ]
        ),
      }),};

Which did not result in any error, but was not the result I was looking for since now ALL includedAchievements need to be present for each user, not just one.
